# postgres equivalent to all_constraints

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql

oracle provides a table ALL_CONSTRAINTS showing details of all constraints defined. For instance I can ask

```
select CONSTRAINT_NAME, DELETE_RULE from ALL_CONSTRAINTS where TABLE_NAME='MY_TABLE'
```

Is there something similar in postgres?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/information-schema.html  and http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalogs.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That information is available in [information_schema](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/information-schema.html).table_constraints:

```
select * 
from information_schema.table_constraints 
where table_name='my_table';
```

edit from user829755:
For showing DELETE_RULE this can be joined with another table:

```
select tc.constraint_name, rc.delete_rule
from information_schema.table_constraints tc
join information_schema.referential_constraints rc using (constraint_name)
where tc.table_name = 'my_table';
```

I found this with the help of following page that shows how to get to tons of other meta data: http://www.alberton.info/postgresql_meta_info.html

Comment: thanks, that works nicely. only it doesn't contain e.g. the DELETE_RULE but it led me to an interesting page showing the full answer, so I extended your answer accordingly

Comment: Good point! I should have dug a bit deeper to match your specific query, but, as you found, between the views in information_schema and the tables in pg_catalog on which they're based, you've got access to anything you need to know.